# Find matching last row and check if the next column row is empty

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that includes an ID and a Name. I'd like to have a procedure that (when the user enters a specific ID) will find the most recent instance of that code in the same column, then will check the next column row if its empty. For example:

```
ID       | Name
SD123456 | John
DF989899 | Alice 
SD123456 | Jason
KA452331 | Wilson
SD123456 | 
DF456790 | Jack
```

As you can see, the ID `'SD123456'` has a missing name, therefore I would like to know if its possible to search for the ID `'SD123456'` and get the last row of that ID and check the next column row if its missing. I've tried using `xlDown` and `xlUp` but to no avail.

EDIT: In summary, my whole VBA purpose is to search for the ID, then check if that latest ID has a name to it, if not, alert the user that, the ID has a missing name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this, simple and clear:

```
Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long
Dim ID As String

lastrow = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
ID = "DF989899"

For i = 2 To lastrow
    If InStr(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value, ID) And IsEmpty(Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value) Then
      MsgBox "Missing Value for ID: " & Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Please note that `End(xlDown)` is not reliable when finding the last row. [This is the proper approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba).

Comment: @BigBen, ya I got it, especially when 1st row is empty, I encounter this issue once before. But most case, `usedrange` and `end(xlDown)` is sufficient depend on your data structure.

Comment: @KinSiang this is interesting but I can foresee a problem, what if there is an entry on Row 7, for example, `DF78901` with a name `Jack`, Row 6 will never be triggered right? Because currently from my understanding, the code only checks for last row

Comment: @KinSiang please note that good VBA answers *don't* use `End(xlDown)` or `UsedRange` to find the last row.

Comment: Just put another condition will do, see my edited answer

Comment: @BigBen, ya i always prefer `usedrange`, but there is once `end(xldown)` is a good method when the data structure has many empty cells but need to reset the range in the looping, i also feel surprise on it

Comment: @KinSiang Thank you, though it's not entirely what I'm looking for but you gave me some ideas, I needed a search function so I think `findEndRow = .Range("A:A").Find(what:="SD123456",after:=.Range("A1"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row` would work? My whole VBA purpose is to search for the ID, then check if that latest ID has a name to it, if not, alert the user that, the ID has a missing name.

Comment: If you just want to check ID by refer to any cell or input, you can use my edited answer, hope this time solve your question...`Find` is not good function in VBA, because if no result is found, it will trigger error

Comment: @KinSiang Yup this solved my problem, thank you, plus I learnt something new from you too, especially on `Find`

Comment: @kraljevocs `Find` is perfectly fine to use, *as long as you test if it succeeded*. That can be done by `Dim foundCell As Range`, `Set foundCell = .Range("A:A").Find(what:="SD123456",after:=.Range("A1"), searchdirection:=xlPrevious)`, then using `If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then` to test if the `Find` did indeed succeed. "`Find` is not good" is just wrong.

Comment: Welcome, try play around with VBA you can learn more thing :)

Comment: @BigBen Ah I see, well that makes sense, having a 'catch' method in an event that the ID could not be found, to prevent compile errors. Thank you!

Comment: Well it would be a runtime error, not a compile error, but yes.

Answer (score 1):

### Find the Last Occurrence of a String in a Column

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CheckIDtest()
    CheckID "SD123456"
End Sub

Sub CheckID(ByVal ID As String)
    
    ' Create references to the ID and Name Column Ranges.
    Dim irg As Range, nrg As Range
    With Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Set irg = .Columns(1)
        Set nrg = .Columns(2)
    End With
    
    ' Attempt to find the last occurrence of the ID.
    Dim fCell As Range
    Set fCell = irg.Find(ID, , xlFormulas, xlWhole, , xlPrevious)
    
    ' ID was not found.
    If fCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The ID '" & ID & "' was not found.", _
            vbCritical, "ID Not Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Write the associated name to a variable.
    ' This complication allows for the columns not to be adjacent.
    Dim fName As String: fName = fCell.EntireRow.Columns(nrg.Column).Value
    ' If they are adjacent like in this case, you could simplify with...
    'fName = fCell.Offset(, 1).Value
    ' ... and forget about 'nrg'. 
    
    If Len(fName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The Name for the ID '" & ID & "' is missing.", _
            vbExclamation, "Missing Name"
    Else
        MsgBox "The Name for the ID '" & ID & "' is '" & fName & "'.", _
            vbInformation, "Name Found"
    End If

End Sub
```